# Why can't I use MediaType.APPLICATION_XML in a @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring

When I change `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` in a Spring `@RequestMapping`, I get the following error in my IDE: “Attribute value must be constant”.

I've dug down into the way `MediaType` constructs its constants - both _JSON and _XML are final variables set in a static initialization block. I can't see any difference between them, but one works and one doesn't.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can u paste your code base ? full class including import statements ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some people in my company are using:

`javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` <-- good

and some people are using:

`org.springframework.http.MediaType` <-- bad (at least in Spring `@RequestMapping`)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-requestmapping.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes)

You should add `'_VALUE'` after the type, only then it becomes a string.

> MediaType provides **constants** for commonly used media types, such as APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE and APPLICATION_XML_VALUE.

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(
    method = {RequestMethod.GET}
)
public @interface GetMapping {
    // ...
    @AliasFor(
        annotation = RequestMapping.class
    )
    String[] consumes() default {};
    // ...
}
```